# Extract part of log file

Tags: regex, bash

I have a log file which looks like this

```
2019-03-15 04:30:41-0400 id:xxxx-84f1-xxxx-85xx-c4xxxx ip:127.0.0.1 apikey:-- rt:47.3ms 200 GET /end/point
-- Request --
some content
....
-- Response --
....
2019-03-15 04:31:00-0500 uid:diffrent-id ip:10.10.10.10. netip:10.10.10.10 apikey:-- rt:309ms 200 GET /some/other/end/point
```

I do have the `id` which is next to the time of occurence. I want to extract everything what is related to this `id` until next occurence and save it to file.

Comment: is the id on every line, or just once, after the time?

Comment: it's only once after the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get everything between two pattern you can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/.* id:.*/,/.* uid:.*/p' log.txt
```

And you'll get

```
-- Request --
some content
....
-- Response --
....
```

where

> `-n`  suppresses automatic printing of pattern space
>
> `p` prints the current pattern space

Comment: That does exactly what I needed! Thank you!